# JQUERY, highlight text, and drag & drop it in a DIV which captures it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'd like a user to be able to highlight a select of text and be able to drag and drop the text selection into a DIV. The DIV would be binded to be able to capture the text that was dropped.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ben Alman's replaceText plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) to set a class on the highlighted text which will allow you to not only style it, but also link to be draggable by [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) to a div that you've predefined and set up with [jQuery UI droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/). Once you've dropped the div inside there is [an event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop) you can bind to, and you'll be able to access the text inside of that.

Comment: Links in respective order:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: Very interesting but how can you use Ben Alman's replaceText plugin to set a class on the highlighted text?

Comment: When you say highlight do you mean actually taking the caret cursor and selecting the text.  Or do you mean the text is highlighted with a background color and you can drag it into a DIV?

Comment: If you are looking for the former, selecting text and getting the selection, there is yet another plugin to solve this:
http://examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php check out example #3